# How to override a JPA entity id column?

Tags: jpa

I use a base entity class for all my entities. It maps to a table that contains columns shared by all entities.

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="entpcd",   discriminatorType=DiscriminatorType.STRING)
@Table(name="enrg")
public abstract class BaseEntity

@Id
@Column(name="enid")
private String entityId=null;
```

And I have an entity class that represents a Person, mapped to its own table.

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("PN")
@Table(name="pn")
public class Person extends BaseEntity
```

**ENRG table structure**

```
enid, col2, col3
```

**PN table structure**

```
pnid, col2 col3
```

While retrieving a Person, Hibernate fails trying to do a join on `enrg.enid=pn.enid`. How do I override id mapping in Person to have Hibernate join on `enrg.enid=pn.pnid`?

Answer (score 1):

`@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="pnid")` solves the problem.

From what I'm reading, Hibernate is having issues with `@AttributeOverride` on id columns. More -> https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=990510