# How override getter of id column in jpa configuration

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, annotations

I have a problem for @Id in JPA that is described as follow?
There is a generic class as follow?

```
    @MappedSuperclass
    public abstract class BaseEntity<T> implements Serializable {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 4295229462159851306L;

        private T id;
        public T getId() {
          return id;
        }
        public void setId(T id) {
           this.id = id;
        }

    }
```

There is another class that extends from it as follow?

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "DOC_CHANGE_CODE" )
 public class ChangeCode extends BaseEntity<Long> {

     @Id
     @GeneratedValue(generator = "sequence_db", strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
     @SequenceGenerator(name = "sequence_db", sequenceName = "SEQ_DOC_CHANGE_CODE", allocationSize = 1)     
     public Long getId () {
       return super.getId();
     }
}
```

Because any sub class has its own sequence, I must specific any subclass @Id, because of that I override the its getter and put some annotations in top of that. Unfortunately it does not work correctly.
How do I fix problem and get my goal?

Comment: "_Unfortunately it does not work correctly_" Can you be more specific ?

Comment: As i has explained, any table has its own sequence. I want to assign those sequence to its table instead of @Generator.

Comment: try using `return this.getId()` instead of `return super.getId()`

Comment: What is difference between super.getId() and this.getId()?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "DOC_CHANGE_CODE" )
@SequenceGenerator(name = "sequence_db", sequenceName = "SEQ_DOC_CHANGE_CODE", allocationSize = 1)     
@AttributeOverride(name = "id", column = @Column(name = "ID"))
public class ChangeCode extends BaseEntity<Long> {

    @Override
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "sequence_db", strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that it works correctly?

Comment: just found this (almost exactly same question) : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5257921/hibernate-how-override-an-attribute-from-mapped-super-class

Comment: Your answer does not work

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to override the `@Id` from a base class.

The only way to do it is to provide [your own custom `IentifierGenerator`](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-combine-the-hibernate-assigned-generator-with-a-sequence-or-an-identity-column/) and provide a different logic based on the subclass (e.g. using a sequence name based on the subclass name).

That's why [adding the `@Id` attribute in the `@MappedSuperclass` only makes sense for the assigned generator or for IDENTITY](https://vladmihalcea.com//how-to-inherit-properties-from-a-base-class-entity-using-mappedsuperclass-with-jpa-and-hibernate/).

Comment: I remove @MappedSuperclass from Generic class and override getter of any filed that i want to be in my entity.It works. Is it correct solution?

Comment: If you removed `@MappedSuperclass`, no property will be inherited, so of course, it works. However, there is no reason why you should keep the base class anymore.

Comment: @VladMihalcea why this is work ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8589928/mappedsuperclass-change-sequencegenerator-in-subclass